# Basic Python: Rank items in list

Tags: python, list, rank

I have a list:

```
[55, 41, 45, 43, 60, 47, 33, 70, 42, 42, 44]
```

I would like to create a new list which ranks these items in the order they are:

Expected Output:

```
[7, ,2 ,9 ,10, 4, 11, 3, 6, 1, 5, 8]
```

Tried these 3 version of the func but its not working properly, not sure why?

```
def argsort(seq):

    #return sorted(range(len(seq)), key = seq.__getitem__)

    #return [i for (v, i) in sorted((v, i) for (i, v) in enumerate(seq))]

    return [x for x,y in sorted(enumerate(seq), key = lambda x: x[1])]
```

returns:

```
[6, 1, 8, 9, 3, 10, 2, 5, 0, 4, 7]
```

Comment: Well if your result is off by 1, why not add 1 to each element?

Comment: Just **look** at your expected and actual outputs - you have a classic off-by-one error, which can be fixed with `x+1 for x, y ...` or `enumerate(seq, 1)`. Python indexes from `0`!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's come up with a more precise definition of what you are after:

> Given a list L of numbers, create a list M that contains the valid indices of L, such that `M[i]` is the index at which the `i`th element of L occurs, when sorted. Present `M` as if the first element of L occurs at index 1.

Now, there are two ways of the valid indices of a list:

1. `range(len(L))`: gives a sequence of numbers 0... len(L)-1
2. `enumerate(L)`: gives a sequence of tuples `(0, L[0])... (len(L)-1, L[len(L)-1])`

Since you want to operate under the assumption that list indices start at 1 (when in fact they start at 0 in python), we need to do a little off-setting

1. `range(len(L))` becomes `range(1, len(L)+1)
2. `enumerate(L)` becomes `enumerate(L, 1)` (the optional argument tells `enumerate` to start numbering at 1)

Since we need the list items as well, let's use `enumerate`, rather than use `range` and do a lookup (I personally prefer this method, though both are valid)

So now, we can get a list of tuples, in which each tuple contains the index of an element in L and the corresponding element in L. We need to sort this by the elements themselves. This can be done with a call to `sorted`, with the optional `key` argument explaining that we should sort by the second element of the tuple (`operator.itemgetter(1)` says exactly this).

Once we have a sorted list of such tuples, all we need to do is extract the first element of each tuple (the index in L), we can use the list-comprehension `[i[0] for i in mylist]`, or equivalently `[operator.itemgetter(0)(t) for t in mylist]`

Putting all these elements together, we get the following

```
In [138]: L = [55, 41, 45, 43, 60, 47, 33, 70, 42, 42, 44]

In [139]: [operator.itemgetter(0)(t) for t in sorted(enumerate(L,1), key=operator.itemgetter(1))]
Out[139]: [7, 2, 9, 10, 4, 11, 3, 6, 1, 5, 8]
```

Comment: Or just `t[0]` instead of `operator.itemgetter(0)(t)`

Comment: Is there any way to handle duplicates, such that for input `[3,4,9,3]`, the output is `[1,2,3,1]`?

Comment: @Gaurav: yes. First do `d = {n:i for i,n in list(enumerate(sorted(set(L)), 1))}`. Then `answer = [d[n] for n in L]`